# How to add DocuSign e-signature request when sending email through google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, docusignapi

I have a google apps script code that sends quote as PDF attachment to my customers. I want my customers to e-sign the quote when they receive the email. Is it possible to attach a DocuSign link in the same email using apps script?

I have no idea how to achieve this. Apologies if this is a naive question but I have not found any related code example upon search.

Comment: Once agreed by the customer, I need them to e-sign

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, irrespective of what the doc should be called, the situation is that I send them the pdf on email using apps script and want them to e-sign. So the question remains how do I include the link to e-sign in the email sent via apps script

Comment: How is it not related to coding? The pdf and the email is sent via apps script. Now in the same email , I want to attach link to e-sign the attached pdf. So the link has to be generated via apps script too

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for the remote singing link to the envelope to be entered into your google apps script. This is something that is not exposed by docuSign intentionally and not something you can generate. The only thing you can generate is an embedded url for the end user to sign, that link however, is designed mostly for short term quick turnaround signatures. The link will only be valid for 5 minutes.

This link should help:
https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/long-lived-embedded-signing-urls